# Perl regex splitting a single line

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having some problems with regex in Perl.

I'm having a line: `#23 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ;`

And I want to split the line into different values.

Right now I have `(#[0-9]+)\s=\s([A-Z]+_[A-Z]+)\s(.*)` this. This will have these values as output:

```
$array[0]=#23
$array[1]=CARTESIAN_POINT
$array[2]=( 'NONE',  ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ;
```

I want this line: `( 'NONE',  ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ;` to split up to different values like.

```
PARAM[0] = 'NONE',
PARAM[1] = ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 )
```

***or***

```
PARAM[0] = 'NONE',
PARAM[1] = -1.822612853216911200
PARAM[2] = 55.22284222837789300
PARAM[3] = 8.566382866014988600
```

But I can't quite figure out how to do it. I tried different things but none of them is mentioning worthy.

I hope someone is able to help me or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward when broken into multiple (two) steps.

First extract the text with coordinates, the stuff inside `CARTESIAN_POINT( ... )`

```
my ($coord_text) = $string =~ /= \s+ [A-Z_]+ \s+ \( \s* (.+) \s* \)/x;
```

where `/x` allows for those spaces inside, for readability. The `.+` is *greedy* and gets everything up to the very last `)`, including the nested `(...)`. 
Then get coordinates out of that

```
my @coords = $coord_text =~ /([A-Z]+|[0-9-.]+)/g;
```

Here we allow *either* a word (like that `NONE`), *or* a number (in shown format<sup>†</sup>).

Altogether, with the intermediate step "hidden" inside a `do` lexical scope

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string = q(#23 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE', ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ; );

my @coords = do {
    my ($coord_text) = $string =~ /=\s+[A-Z_]+\s+\(\s*(.+)\s*\)/; 
    $coord_text =~ /([A-Z]+|[0-9-.]+)/g;
};

say for @coords;
```

This is easily tweaked for variations in requirements/outcomes, slight or major

- To capture quotes around `NONE` as well (shown in OP), add quotes to the character class for the word, `[A-Z\x22\x27]`. I use hex in case this is a "one-liner" in a bash script or some such, since context isn't specified.  In a normal script you can use `"` and `'`
- To get numbers in a string instead of a list, as mentioned in the question, use

  ```
  $coord_text =~ /([A-Z]+|\([^)]+\))/g;
  ```

  instead of the second statement in the `do` block above

I assume that you have a list containing either words (like `NONE`) or straight lists of coordinates (numbers), without any further nesting or similar syntactic complexities.

**Note**  If the input can be a multiline string then add `/s` modifier to the regex. With it the `.` matches a newline as well and it all works the same as above (it does in my tests).  This should only be needed in the first regex, making it

```
my ($coord_text) = $string =~ /=\s+[A-Z_]+\s+\(\s*(.+)\s*\)/s;
```

but it won't hurt in the other one either.

---

<sup>†</sup> The used character class `[0-9-.]` also allows garbage (like `-.-2` etc). If you need to confirm that you indeed have a number in the given format please add checks for that.  The best way to test for a number is `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  I’ll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: @mHvNG You are most welcome.  Note that I edited a little in the meanwhile, and in particular I just added a "**Note**" at the end about how to modify it to work with multiline stirngs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is what [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) is for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Balanced qw[extract_bracketed];
use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Extract the bit of your string between the first and last brackets
  my $extracted = extract_bracketed($_, '(', '[^()]*');
  # Then split what's left on strings of brackets, whitespace and commas.
  # But grep the list to remove any zero-length strings that you get.
  my @bits = grep { length } split /[\(\)\s,]+/, $extracted;
  print Dumper \@bits;
}

__DATA__
#23 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '\'NONE\'',
          '-1.822612853216911200',
          '55.22284222837789300',
          '8.566382866014988600'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat your pattern as many times as needed and supply the appropriate capture groups:

```
#[0-9]+\s*=\s*[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\s*\(\s*'([A-Z]+)',\s*\(\s*(-?\d+\.\d+),\s*(-?\d+\.\d+),\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/GJ6yDi/1/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the nesting, and just want to get all the "values" into an array, you might consider the simpler solution of just splitting on a discard of all unwanted (non-value) characters: `/[(),;=\s]+/`

```
$ cat line
#23 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( -1.822612853216911200, 55.22284222837789300, 8.566382866014988600 ) ) ;

$ perl -ne '@array = split /[(),;=\s]+/; print join "|", @array; print "\n"' line
#23|CARTESIAN_POINT|'NONE'|-1.822612853216911200|55.22284222837789300|8.566382866014988600
```