# Perl regex transform multiline to a single line

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I'm having some problem with transforming a multi line string to a single line string.

I have a string like this:

```
#66 = B_SPLINE_CURVE_WITH_KNOTS ( 'NONE', 3,
 ( #62, #61, #105, #104, #103, #102, #101, #100, #99, #98 ),
 .UNSPECIFIED., .F., .F.,
 ( 4, 3, 3, 4 ),
 ( 7.785145389033986000E-018, 0.0001260065739121398800, 0.0001891785121403045300, 0.0002523514299847038200 ),
 .UNSPECIFIED. ) ;
```

But I need it as one whole line.

**This is what I tried:**

```
/^#[0-9].*;)$/s/
```

***What I'm trying to do:***

```
#[0-9]
```

This points to the `#66`. The reason for this `#[0-9]` is it needs to be dynamic.

```
.*
```

This points to everything between the `;`

```
;
```

This points to the end of the line. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

***My regex now:***

```
/([^\n]*)\n* /g
```

Comment: What is the output that you're expecting?

Comment: If you want everything on a single line, can't you just remove all \n ?

Comment: @CinCout The string in the question, but in one single line.

Comment: @LogicalKip Well no, because I have a file with 80.000 lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I’ll try it out.

Comment: @CinCout Thanks! If you make it an answer I’ll accept it!

Comment: This appears to be a follow-up to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57892089/4653379), which I answered (and you kindly accepted) but without considering a multiline string.  If this is indeed the case, that answer will work with multiline strings as well -- you only need to add `/s` modifier to the regex.  (A "modifier" is what you add after, like `/.../s`.)  I added a comment at the end of my [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893600/4653379).

Comment: @zdim Thanks! I just saw it and commented. I totally forgot it.

Comment: Yeah, saw that :)   Btw, these strings now are a little different but you can modify the regex in that answer to work with them as well -- add to those character classes (`[...]`) additional characters to accept, like `#` (for `#62` etc) or `.` (for `.F.` etc), depending on what you want to capture out of all terms.

Comment: @zdim Yeah, i already did that yesterday. So theorically it should work now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

`([^\n]*)\n* /g`

Just capture everything except the newline character until the newline character is encountered per line.

Then substitute with the captured group `$1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2b6ZUl/3)

Comment: How do I add the substitute in Perl?

Comment: Because when I add the regex in my perl script it doesn’t add the ‘;’ to the string. I dont know if the substitutie helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking. I think you are asking how to remove the line feeds from a string. That can be achieved using the following:

```
$str =~ s/\n//g;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do is delete the newlines. So I can split the string from the #1234 to the semicolon. But my problem is when I delete the newlines it doesn't add the semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: So now instead of this : "#14 = VERTEX_POINT ( 'NONE', #50707 ) ;" I get this: "#14 = VERTEX_POINT ( 'NONE', #50707 ) ". Without the semicolon.

Comment: and the same with the example in my question.

Comment: I'm using the answer of @CinCout, but in the answer he mentions  "Then substitute with the captured group $1". I don't know how to do that in Perl.

Comment: Re "*I'm trying to do is delete the newlines.*", "Newline" doesn't actually mean anything, and that doesn't say from what. Do you mean you want to delete line feeds from a string? That's what the code in my answer does. I even said as much. /// I don't see what any of the other comments have to do with my answer.